# Can I access my companion's inventory when they're not in my active party?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I have recently acquired a new party member, but given that the party maximum is 4, she tells me she'll wait for me in my camp. So I go to camp, tell Wyll to take a load off, and recruit my new companion!

...only to realize that Wyll was wielding the magic dagger I wanted to give her, and, well, I can't seem to reach his equipment, anymore.

Is there a way to access your inactive companion's inventories short of doing the party shuffle? (Heavens forbid you forget whomst is holding what!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this I am using the Camp Chest.

If you right click an item in your inventory you can select 'Send to Camp'. On PC, you can also use Shift or Ctrl + LMB to multi-select.

This will place it inside the chest in your camp.

Then when you visit camp you can retrieve it from the chest and pass it to whomever you need. So I tend to dump everything my party are not actively using into the chest, and then my new party can go select what items they might need for the next adventure.

I do not know of a way to see a companions inventory without having them in the party.

Comment: Yep, it seems like better inventory management with party members is one of the main quality-of-life feature requests for the game right now.